# how to update multi select autocomplete dropdown collection in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[Demo Link Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JOxVp1vBRiiuhIdeqLcf?p=preview)

Hi friends,

Here I tried parent child multi select autocomplete dropdown. based on the selection Child dropdown value need to update.

```
   $scope.$watch('item', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.allSubitems =[];
  angular.forEach($scope.item, function(value, key) {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
      console.log('calling')
        $scope.allSubitems.push({"Id":value.name + i,"name":"sub "+ value.name +"("+ i+ ")"});
    }
  })
   })
```

I tried like this every thing working fine but the collection value not affected in UI. may i know where i did mistake.